# Ubuntu 14.04 keeps crashing after login

Tags: 14.04, crash, mate

Okay, so I can boot up and login into my system, but will only last few seconds, then I get blank screen and then the system restarts after a few moments.

System details:

Ubuntu 14.04

Processor: AMD A10-6800K
Motherboard: Asus F2A85-V PRO
RAM is 8GB

Comment: more details tryed running ubuntu mate from live usb and it crashed as well

Answer (score 0):

Most likely caused by a problem with a graphics driver.  What video card or graphics chip (GPU) do you have?

You may be able to work around it by setting either "xforcevesa" or "nomodeset" kernel boot parameters in Grub.  Just search for either of these terms as there are many howtos for setting them in Ubuntu.  These will either bypass or disable the default graphics driver and allow you to login and install the correct driver.